# if value in column is NaN create new column with label incomplete

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe.

```
     a  b
0  NaN  2
1  2.0  4
2  NaN  7
```

I'm trying to create a new column, by checking the type of value in column 'a' and assigning a new label accordingly. The result should look like this:

```
     a  b  c
0  NaN  2  incomplete
1  2.0  4  complete
2  NaN  7  incomplete
```

The code is:

```
if data_frame['a'].isna() == True: 
   data_frame['c'] = 'incomplete'
else:
   data_frame['c'] = 'complete'
```

I'm trying to use a simple if / else statement but I get this error:

```
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not so sure on that error. I would have imagined something else (along the lines of the truth value being ambiguous). Are you using this code in a loop?

Comment: The SyntaxError is probably caused by an included quote character on a previous line.

Comment: But if you fix that, you will probably just get the error roganjosh mentioned. And., if not, you’ll just be creating and entire column that’s either complete or incomplete for every row. You can’t use a simple if/else statement for this; you have to create an array or Series of multiple values, one per row, like, ideally as a single array operation on the a column.

Comment: Something like isna().map({True: "incomplete", False: "complete"})

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using `np.where` though it would require an additional import

```
df['c'] = np.where(df.a.notnull(), 'complete', 'incomplete')
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily require an additional import, you could use `pd.np.where`, but when using `pandas`, `numpy` basically goes hand in hand anyways.

Comment: @user3483203 I found `pd.np` so confusing when I first saw it :)

Comment: @user3483203 I didn't know you could do that... this is why I use SO

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Series.apply`

```
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'complete' if not np.isnan(x) else 'incomplete')
```

Output

```
     a  b           c
0  NaN  2  incomplete
1  2.0  4    complete
2  NaN  7  incomplete
```

---

Timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit df['a'].notnull().map({True:'complete',False:'incomplete'})
667 µs ± 2.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'complete' if not np.isnan(x) else 'incomplete')
4.67 ms ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

 %timeit np.where(df['a'].notnull(), 'complete', 'incomplete')
145 µs ± 870 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Seems like the best solution for performance is np.where (+1 @roganjosh)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `apply` as it's no better (and normally performs worse) than a regular loop.

Comment: @jpp fair -- added timings

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need a loop here

```
df['a'].notnull().map({True:'complete',False:'incomplete'})
Out[347]: 
0      complete
1    incomplete
2      complete
dtype: object
```

Comment: You have your booleans swapped. `True` should point to `'incomplete'`

Comment: Wouldn't `np.where` be faster for a binary choice?